# What happens if two non-adjacent corners of the feasible region gives optimal solution for a linear programming question?

Tags: solution-verification, linear-programming

In a [linear programming](https://www.britannica.com/science/linear-programming-mathematics) question, let's assume that the feasible region is a polygon. Now let's consider an objective function whose value we want to be minimised. What would happen if I get two non-adjacent points at the vertices of the polygon that gives me the least possible value (and hence the optimal solution)?

Would the line segment joining the 2 points give me the set of optimal solutions? Or will I have only two solutions? And what would happened if I get three points that give me the optimal solution? Would a triangle be my solution set?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do know that if any part of the connecting line segment between two "optimal" points is in the feasible region, then there will be another corner point that actually beats them, no?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Oh yes I forgot to mention, is it possible for two non-adjacent "optimal" points?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Maybe it may happen in a concave polygon?

Comment: Show me a case with a concave polygon ... .

Comment: @OscarLanzi will try... let the four points of the feasible region is A =(0,0) B=(10,10) C=(70,0) D=(0,70).  Now lets assume our objective function Z= x+y ... so wouldn't the optimal solutions be B and D?

Comment: (I realised I made a mistake in the second comment. I meant to say is it possible for two non-adjacent "optimal" points to exist? I dealt only with adjacent points)

Comment: So how is that concave region you kention made with Inequality constraints?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Ah i see, concave regions are not possible, non-adjacent optimal points are also not possible. Is that the conclusion?

Comment: Yup, once you have convexity you can't have nonadjacent corner-point solutions. That includes the vertices of a triangle where two of them are nonadjacent; in that case with a convex region the third vertex beats them both.